# array || illegal offset type

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, offset

hello guys i got problem with the arrays. i want to save array to the table but i receive this :

```
illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\app-mt\php\proses-edit-aplikasi.php on line 13

illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\app-mt\php\proses-edit-aplikasi.php on line 14

illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\app-mt\php\proses-edit-aplikasi.php on line 15
```

it show to this code

```
[1] => $value1,
[2] => $value2,
[3] => $value3
```

this is full of code

```
$value1 = $_POST['value1'];
$value2 = $_POST['value2'];
$value3 = $_POST['value3'];

$data_value = Array(
[1] => $value1,
[2] => $value2,
[3] => $value3
);
$array_value = serialize($data_value);

$query = "UPDATE maintenance
    SET pic                                 = '$pic',
        application_name                    = '$nama',
        maintenance_date                    = '$tanggal',
        entry_by                            = '$pictrans'

    WHERE maintenance_id = '$id'";
$query2 = "UPDATE INTO maintenance_detail
    SET value                               = '$array_value'

    WHERE maintenance_detail_id = '$id'";

$hasil = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$hasil2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are using arrays as keys for the new array. `[..]` is the short way to define a new array. If you want numeric keys, just get rid of the round brackets around.

```
$data_value = Array(
    1 => $value1,
    2 => $value2,
    3 => $value3
);
```